# Event.source Returns null in BroadcastChannel - javascript

Tags: javascript, events, window, message, broadcast

So I was trying to reference another window that was in another tab, but on the same domain. I created a BroadcastChannel, thinking that I could have one window send a message to the channel, and the other window use event.source to reference it:
**First window:**

```
var bc=new BroadcastChannel('bc');
bc.onmessage=function(e) {console.log(e.source, 'said:', e.data);};
```

**Second window:**

```
var bc=new BroadcastChannel('bc');
bc.postMessage('Hello, world!');
```

The problem is, it logs to the console:

```
null
said:  
Hello, world!
```

Why is event.source returning null?

Comment: should it not be `source` or `origin` rather than `src`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent

Comment: Yes. Sorry I posted it wrong, but when I tried the code, I used `source` and it returned `null`.

Comment: I will fix this. Thank you!